# jQuery cloning or moving ajax info from another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, clone

I am attempting to clone (or move) information from one page to another using jQuery and ajax.  This code currently does nothing for me and is all I have to work with:

Essentially it is checking the page for id `Deal_1`.  If found I want to move (or clone) these three divs **that are on the page being checked** with classes `deal-product-name` `deal-saving-stock-details` & `deal-end`, to the page I am currently on.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/dealoftheday.asp",
context: document.body,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data){      
        if ($(data).find('#Deal_1').length >= 1) {                          
            $('#dealofdaytop').after($('.deal-product-name')); 
            $('#dealdayprice').after($('.deal-saving-stock-details'));
            $('#dealdayprice').after($('.deal-end'));      
        }
});
```

This is on current page I want the divs moved to:

```
<div class="deal" id="dealday">
  <div id="dealofdaytop" align="center"><img style="opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80)" src="http://www.mysite.com/v/newsite/dealofday/dealofdaytop.png"> </div>
  <div id="dealdayprice" style="height: 60px;"></div>  
  <div id="dealdaybg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: should u not use .append() intead of .after() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be like this;

```
if ($(data).find('#Deal_1').length >= 1) {                                      
    $('#dealofdaytop').after($('.deal-product-name', data));
    $('#dealdayprice').after($('.deal-saving-stock-details', data));
    $('#dealdayprice').after($('.deal-end', data));              
}
```

Working example code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/WebApplication1/WebForm2.aspx",
        context: document.body,
        success: function (data) {
            $(".dummy_container").after($(".deal-product-name", data));
        }
    });
});
```

Contents of WebForm1.aspx

```
<div class="dummy_container"></div>
```

Contents of WebForm2.aspx

```
<div id="Deal_1">
    <div class="deal-product-name">
        Test data
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still no luck.  Do I need a POST request or something?

Comment: .deal-product-name is a class belonging to some element from dealoftheday.asp right?

Comment: That is correct. those classes are all on dealoftheday.asp, which im trying to move (or clone) to another page.

Comment: Then you are just missing something. Above code works for me. Could .deal-product-name be #deal-product-name?

Comment: you know your right, I am getting a response with a relative link on my site.  I will do a little more debugging but im sure this is it, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll post another answer so you can check what's on my test code.

Answer (score 0):

In your success handler, you're trying to use jQuery DOM functions directly on the returned data which is just a string here.  As far as I know, you can't do that.  If the result of your ajax call is HTML and you want to insert that into your page, you can then use jQuery DOM functions on it or you can use regex functions directly on the string.

This problem in general looks to me like you may want the response to be JSON with the different parts of the response in different returned objects and you can then reach into those objects with javascript, grab the result you're looking for and use that to modify the appropriate part of your page.